# Underscore to flatten nested array of parent/child objects

Tags: underscore.js

I have an array of objects, where each object has a "children" property (example data below). I want to flatten parents/children into a single array, with each parent immediately followed by it's children.

I've written the following using lo-dash / underscore, and it works when I have one and only one child for each parent:

```
_.flatten(_.zip(myArr, _.flatten(myArr, "children")))
```

I know I can use something like _.each and build an object, just wondering if there's a snazzy way to do this using _.

Example Data:

```
[{
    name: "Some Name",
    value: 1234,
    children: [{
        name: "Another name",
        value: 3456
    }, {
        name: "A third name",
        value: 9876
    }]
}, {
    name: "Omg Lazer Guns",
    value: 3333,
    children: [{
        name: "PewPewPew",
        value: 4444
    }]
}];
```

Comment: I guess you meant `pluck` instead of `flatten` inside the zip?

Comment: http://lodash.com/docs#flatten - the shorthand version uses `pluck`, yes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A simple and more readable way to do this is

```
var list = [];
_.each(data, function(item){
    list.push(_.omit(item, 'children'));
    list.push(_.flatten(_.pick(item, 'children')));
});
var result = _.flatten(list);
```

The result is

```
[{
    "name": "Some Name",
    "value": 1234
}, {
    "name": "Another name",
    "value": 3456
}, {
    "name": "A third name",
    "value": 9876
}, {
    "name": "Omg Lazer Guns",
    "value": 3333
}, {
    "name": "PewPewPew",
    "value": 4444
}]
```

Comment: Output is not comming

Comment: It does not returns the children.

Comment: I have tested this and it does only return the parent, not the children, see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jjxwz49r49

Answer (score 5):

The usual approach to merge arrays they way you want to is to [`zip`](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) them and You can use [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to extract the children. Something like this:

```
var mangled = _(myArr).chain()
                      .zip(_(myArr).pluck('children'))
                      .flatten() 
                      .value()
```

That will leave you with `undefined` entries in `mangled` if any of the top-level elements of `myArr` don't have `children` keys at all. You can throw in a [`compact`](http://underscorejs.org/#compact) to get rid of those:

```
var mangled = _(myArr).chain()
                      .zip(_(myArr).pluck('children'))
                      .flatten()
                      .compact()
                      .value()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aeS86/

Of course, doing the mangling with a a couple `for` loops and some [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) calls will probably be faster but the speed difference shouldn't matter with short arrays.

Comment: In *mangled*, the parent object still contains the children field, how to remove it?

Comment: I'd probably go with something like yours for that. In real life I'd probably use `for` loops and `push` to flatten and clean it up in one pass. The problem (IMO) is that we don't have real iterators so there's a ton of copying and array constructor that happens.

Comment: I could go back and forth on which answer is "correct" - I guess this is a little subjective. Since your comment said you'd use his, I marked his as answer. Plus, you have 30x reputation :)

Comment: No worries, sza's solution is fine (one of those upvotes is mine BTW).

Answer (score 0):

For one-level children

```js
let data = [{
    name: "Some Name", value: 1234,
    children: [{
        name: "Another name", value: 3456
    }, {
        name: "A third name", value: 9876
    }]
}, {
    name: "Omg Lazer Guns", value: 3333,
    children: [{
        name: "PewPewPew", value: 4444
    }]
}, { name: "i", value: 0 }];

let nestedArray =_.map(data, (node)=>node.children?[node, ...node.children]:[node]);
let simpleArray = _.flatten(nestedArray);
console.log(simpleArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question originally asked for a snazzy way that avoided procedural code. Here is a declarative, recursive implementation with Underscore that works to arbitrary depth:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "Some Name",
    value: 1234,
    children: [{
        name: "Another name",
        value: 3456
    }, {
        name: "A third name",
        value: 9876
    }]
}, {
    name: "Omg Lazer Guns",
    value: 3333,
    children: [{
        name: "PewPewPew",
        value: 4444
    }]
}];

// Recursive pre-order traversal.
var equalize = parent => [_.omit(parent, 'children')]
.concat(_.map(parent.children, equalize));

// Obtaining the final result.
console.log(_.chain(data).map(equalize).flatten().value());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```