# flatten a list of objects with nested lists of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a javascript list in the form of:

```
var list = [{id:1, data: "string", list: [
              {id:2, data: "string", list: [
                {id:3, data: "string", list: null}]},
              {id:4, data: "string", list: null}]}];
```

And I want it to be in the form of:

```
var list = [{id:1, data: "string", list: \\ original nested list or null, I don't care},
            {id:2, data: "string", list:},
            {id:3, data: "string", list:},
            {id:4, data: "string", list:}];
```

I have access to underscore.js, but I haven't been able to produce the output I want. 
I tried using a combination of `_.flatten` and `_.pluck` to get the underlying list, but I also need the `id` property so this doesn't work. 
My guess is that I need to map a function, but I'm kind of lost on the issue right now.

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: [like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003083/underscore-to-flatten-nested-array-of-parent-child-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursion to do it:

```
function flatten(arr) {
    if (!arr) {
        return [];
    }
    return arr.reduce(function (r, i) {
        return r.concat([i]).concat(flatten(i.list));
    }, []);
}

console.log(flatten(list));
```

With ES6 syntax (arrow functions and spread operator) it could look like this:

```
function flatten(arr) {
    return arr ? arr.reduce((r, i) => [...r, i, ...flatten(i.list)], []) : [];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted