# Flatten a nested array of objects over a array field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

Have an object a1 =

```
[{name:'x',age:21, addr:[{flat:1,add:'xyz'},{flat:2,add:'xsr'}]},
{name:'y',age:22, addr:[{flat:3,add:'xyz1'},{flat:4,add:'xsr1'}]]
```

Desired output:

```
[{name:'x',age:21, addr:{flat:1,add:'xyz'}},
{name:'x',age:21, addr:{flat:2,add:'xsr'}},
{name:'y',age:22, addr:{flat:3,add:'xyz1'},
{name:'y',age:22, addr:{flat:4,add:'xsr1'}]
```

Please suggest! I am trying to accomplish this using lodash/underscore.

Comment: You have to loop over the array and for every element create as many new substitution objects as there are in the `addr` property, nothing hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscore to flatten nested array of parent/child objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003083/underscore-to-flatten-nested-array-of-parent-child-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map every item in the original array to a new array, with a number of items according to the number of `addr` fields. Using concat flatten everything to a new array.

You can create new items using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) if you're transpiling to ES5 with babel or similar, as it's not supported by IE. However, since you're using angular, you can use [`angular.extend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) instead.

ES5:

```js
var arr = [
  {name:'x',age:21, addr:[{flat:1,add:'xyz'},{flat:2,add:'xsr'}]},
  {name:'y',age:22, addr:[{flat:3,add:'xyz1'},{flat:4,add:'xsr1'}]}
];
   
var result = [].concat.apply([], arr.map(function(item) {     
  return item.addr.map(function(addr) {
    return angular.extend({}, item, { addr: addr });
  });
}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

ES6:

```js
const arr = [
  {name:'x',age:21, addr:[{flat:1,add:'xyz'},{flat:2,add:'xsr'}]},
  {name:'y',age:22, addr:[{flat:3,add:'xyz1'},{flat:4,add:'xsr1'}]}
];
   
const result = [].concat(...arr.map((item) => item.addr.map((addr) => Object.assign({}, item, { addr }))));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and the inner array for building the wanted result.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'x', age: 21, addr: [{ flat: 1, add: 'xyz' }, { flat: 2, add: 'xsr' }] }, { name: 'y', age: 22, addr: [{ flat: 3, add: 'xyz1' }, { flat: 4, add: 'xsr1' }] }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.addr.map(function (b) {
            return { name: a.name, age: a.age, addr: b };
        }));
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var array = [{ name: 'x', age: 21, addr: [{ flat: 1, add: 'xyz' }, { flat: 2, add: 'xsr' }] }, { name: 'y', age: 22, addr: [{ flat: 3, add: 'xyz1' }, { flat: 4, add: 'xsr1' }] }],
    result = array.reduce((r, a) => r.concat(a.addr.map(b => ({ name: a.name, age: a.age, addr: b }))), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()`, `forEach()` and `Object.assign()` to return desired result.

```js
var data = [{name:'x',age:21, addr:[{flat:1,add:'xyz'},{flat:2,add:'xsr'}]},
{name:'y',age:22, addr:[{flat:3,add:'xyz1'},{flat:4,add:'xsr1'}]}];

var result = data.reduce(function(r, o) {
  o.addr.forEach(function(e) {
    r.push(Object.assign({name: o.name, age: o.age}, e));
  })
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```