# Creating a new array with all the elements of subarray

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to create an output array which takes all the parameters from its subarray and create a resulting array.
Hard to explain in words, so am explaining with an example below.

```
var myArr=[
                {
                    "Id":1,
                    "Name":'Ken',
                    "Age" : '30',
                    "Hobbies" : [{'HobbyId':1,'HobbyName':'Swimming'},{'HobbyId':2,'HobbyName':'Reading'}],
                    "Skills" : [{'SkillId':1,'SkillName':'PHP'},{'SkillId':2,'SkillName':'MySQL'}],
                    "Language" : [{'LangId':2,'LangName':'English'},{'LangId':3,'LangName':'Chinese'}]
                },
                {
                    "Id":2,
                    "Name":'Mike',
                    "Age" : '20',
                    "Hobbies" : [],
                    "Skills" : [],
                    "Language" : []
                },
                {
                    "Id":3,
                    "Name":'Charlie',
                    "Age" : '25',
                    "Hobbies" : [{'HobbyId':5,'HobbyName':'Dance'},{'HobbyId':6,'HobbyName':'Sing'},{'HobbyId':7,'HobbyName':'Writing'}],
                    "Skills" : [],
                    "Language" : [{'Id':7,'Name':'English'}]
                }
            ]
```

In the above example there are 3 subarrays named Hobbies, Skills and Languages.
    I'll have some more subarrays apart from these three.
    I actually want to remove the subarray logic and make it a flat array.

So, when creating this flat array I want to consider all the parameters from subarray even if the subarray is empty.
    So my first item of resulting array will have the first item of all subarrays and so on.
    Even if the subarray is an empty array I need to consider there keys and input the value as null.

And so my resulting array will be as below :

```
var resultArray = [
                 {
                    "Id":1,
                    "Name":'Ken',
                    "Age" : '30',  
                    "HobbyId" : 1,
                    "HobbyName" : 'Swimming',
                    "SkillId" : 1,
                    "SkillName":'PHP',
                    "LangId" : 2,
                    "LangName" : 'English'
                 },
                 {
                    "Id":1,
                    "Name":'Ken',
                    "Age" : '30',  
                    "HobbyId" : 2,
                    "HobbyName" : 'Reading',
                    "SkillId" : 2,
                    "SkillName":'MySQL',
                    "LangId" : 3,
                    "LangName" : 'Chinese'
                 },
                 {
                    "Id":2,
                    "Name":'Mike',
                    "Age" : '20',
                    "HobbyId" : '',
                    "HobbyName" : '' ,
                    "SkillId" : '',
                    "SkillName":'',
                    "LangId" : '',
                    "LangName" : ''
                 },
                 {
                    "Id":3,
                    "Name":'Charlie',
                    "Age" : '25',
                    "HobbyId" : 5,
                    "HobbyName" : 'Dance',
                    "SkillId" : '',
                    "SkillName":'',
                    "LangId" : 7,
                    "LangName" : 'English'
                 },
                 {
                    "Id":3,
                    "Name":'Charlie',
                    "Age" : '25',
                    "HobbyId" : 6,
                    "HobbyName" : 'Sing',
                    "SkillId" : '',
                    "SkillName":'',
                    "LangId" : '',
                    "LangName" : ''
                 },
                 {
                    "Id":3,
                    "Name":'Charlie',
                    "Age" : '25',
                    "HobbyId" : 7,
                    "HobbyName" : 'Writing',
                    "SkillId" : '',
                    "SkillName":'',
                    "LangId" : '',
                    "LangName" : ''
                 }
             ]
```

Comment: While it is possible and relatively easy (you'll probably get some answers soon), it's a bad idea to do this as you're mixing up your data entities. You end up having 2 Kens and 3 Charlies. Why do you want this?

Comment: I need to create a a table using jqGrid with some rowspans so actually 2 Kens and 3 Charlies will be rowspanned as 1 and display their respective Hobbies etc in front of the row and that's the only way to achieve with jqGrid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten a nested array of objects over a array field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250107/flatten-a-nested-array-of-objects-over-a-array-field)

Comment: That other question is a little bit easier as you can use lodash/underscore.

Comment: This is a bad idea. It relates things that do not have a relationship. Why would the second hobby have anything more to do with the second skill and second language than any other skill or language? --> don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to produce what you wanted:

```
let results = [];
for(let {Id, Name, Age, Hobbies, Skills, Language} of myArr) {
    let numRows = Math.max(1, Hobbies.length, Skills.length, Language.length);
    for (let i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
        let {HobbyId, HobbyName} = Hobbies[i] || {};
        let {SkillId, SkillName} = Skills[i] || {};
        let {LangId, LangName} = Language[i] || {};
        results.push({
            Id, Name, Age,
            HobbyId, HobbyName,
            SkillId, SkillName,
            LangId, LangName,
        });
    }
}
console.table(results);
```

[image]

The non-trivial bits are:

- I use quite a bit of ES6 syntax. You might want to read a bit more about [object destructuring](http://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/), [shorthand object literals](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals) and [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).
- I calculate the number of rows needed before starting iteration so that I don't have to check every time whether I should go to the next person or not.
- I do `Hobbies[i] || {}` in order to make sure that I always have an object to desctructure with `let {HobbyId, HobbyName}`. I do it this way because it's simpler than checking for `null` each time.