# Flatten an nested array of objects using Lodash

Tags: lodash

My object looks like this:

```
const features = [{
                  'name': 'feature1', 'tags':
                  [{'weight':10, 'tagName': 't1'},{'weight':20, 'tagName': 't2'}, {'weight':30, 'tagName': 't3'}]
                  },
                  {
                  'name': 'feature2', 'tags':
                  [{'weight':40, 'tagName': 't1'}, {'weight':5, 'tagName':'t2'}, {'weight':70, 'tagName':'t3'}]
                  },
                  {
                  'name': 'feature3', 'tags':[
                  {'weight':50, 'tagName': 't1'}, {'weight':2, 'tagName': 't2'}, {'weight':80, 'tagName': 't3'}]
                 }]
```

I would like my output to look something like this:

```
const features = [{'name':'feature1', 'weight':10, 'tagName':'t1'}, 
                  {'name':'feature1', 'weight':20, 'tagName':'t2'}, ...
                  {'name':'feature3', 'weight':80, 'tagName':'t3'}]
```

I tried to `merge` and the `flatten` but it does not work.

**Update 1**
I tried this:

```
let feat = features;

results = []

_.each(feat, (item) => { 
                        console.log(item);
                        results.push(_.flatten(_.pick(item.tags, 'weight'))); // pick for certain keys. 
                       }
```

**Update 2**
This solved my problem

```
_.each(features, (item) => { 
  _.each(item.tags, (itemTag) => { 
    results.push({'name':item.name, 'weight':itemTag.weight, 'tagName':itemTag.tagName})})})
```

But I want to know if there is a more `lodash` way to do this!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscore to flatten nested array of parent/child objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003083/underscore-to-flatten-nested-array-of-parent-child-objects) This talks about underscore, but should work for lodash too.

Comment: That quite didn't work for me :/

Comment: Please [edit] your question showing what you have tried and how it didn't work for you.

Comment: I also tried another method to `_.merge` the `item.tags` but it didn't work since it has the same keys. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The approach below uses [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) to flatten `tags` acquired through [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map). Finally, use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to assign the values from `tag` and the `feature`'s name.

```
const result = _.flatMap(features, ({ name, tags }) =>
  _.map(tags, tag => ({ name, ...tag }))
);
```

```js
const features = [{
    'name': 'feature1',
    'tags': [{
      'weight': 10,
      'tagName': 't1'
    }, {
      'weight': 20,
      'tagName': 't2'
    }, {
      'weight': 30,
      'tagName': 't3'
    }]
  },
  {
    'name': 'feature2',
    'tags': [{
      'weight': 40,
      'tagName': 't1'
    }, {
      'weight': 5,
      'tagName': 't2'
    }, {
      'weight': 70,
      'tagName': 't3'
    }]
  },
  {
    'name': 'feature3',
    'tags': [{
      'weight': 50,
      'tagName': 't1'
    }, {
      'weight': 2,
      'tagName': 't2'
    }, {
      'weight': 80,
      'tagName': 't3'
    }]
  }
];

const result = _.flatMap(features, ({ name, tags }) =>
  _.map(tags, tag => ({ name, ...tag }))
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Here's a plain javascript solution that uses [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with the help of [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to flatten the array.

```
const result = features.reduce(
  (result, { name, tags }) => result
    .concat(tags.map(tag => ({ name, ...tag }))), 
  []
);
```

```js
const features = [{
    'name': 'feature1',
    'tags': [{
      'weight': 10,
      'tagName': 't1'
    }, {
      'weight': 20,
      'tagName': 't2'
    }, {
      'weight': 30,
      'tagName': 't3'
    }]
  },
  {
    'name': 'feature2',
    'tags': [{
      'weight': 40,
      'tagName': 't1'
    }, {
      'weight': 5,
      'tagName': 't2'
    }, {
      'weight': 70,
      'tagName': 't3'
    }]
  },
  {
    'name': 'feature3',
    'tags': [{
      'weight': 50,
      'tagName': 't1'
    }, {
      'weight': 2,
      'tagName': 't2'
    }, {
      'weight': 80,
      'tagName': 't3'
    }]
  }
];

const result = features.reduce(
  (result, { name, tags }) => result
    .concat(tags.map(tag => ({ name, ...tag }))), 
  []
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @ryeballar! this is beautiful.

Comment: what if we want to retrieve only **highest weight** ones?  Thanks in advance

Comment: @cilerler post that as another question.

Comment: @ryeballar never mind, figured out that as `return _.maxBy(_.map(item.tags, tag => _.defaults({ name: item.name }, tag)),item.weight);`  thanks for the response.