# How do I can split an array of objects that contains another arrays by Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, collections, lodash

I have this array: `[{ name: "A1", arr: [1,2] }, { name: "A2", arr: [1] }]`

How do I can split the first one object to two objects that should contains only one array value?

The result should be:

```
[{name: "A1", arr: [1] }, {name: "A1", arr: [2]}, {name: "A2", arr: [1] }]
```

I didn't find anything universal tool that can help to resolve this issue in the lodash documentation. (Actually I use lodash very rare so that's why I asked to help me).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would use a reduce function. I can give you an example solution with that if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the data using `Array#map`, create the separate objects using a 2nd `Array#map`, and then flatten them by spreading the results and using `Array#concat` on them:

```js
var data = [{ name: "A1", arr: [1,2] }, { name: "A2", arr: [1] }];

var result = [].concat(...data.map((item) => item.arr.map((num) => Object.assign({}, item, { arr: [num] }))));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you Ori for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with [`#Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) function :

```
[{ name: "A1", arr: [1,2] }, { name: "A2", arr: [1] }].reduce((acc, val) => {
   val.arr.forEach(el => {
     acc.push({name: val.name, arr: [el]});
   });
   return acc;
}, [])
```

### EDIT

With `map` and `concat` as  @Ian Segers suggested (thanks) :

```
[{ name: "A1", arr: [1,2] }, { name: "A2", arr: [1] }].reduce((acc, val) => 
  acc.concat(val.arr.map(el => {
     return  {name: val.name, arr: [el]}
   })), [])
```

Best regards,

Comment: You can change the `val.arr.forEach` to a `val.arr.map`, but in that case your push need to replaced with a `concat` etc..

Comment: I think you also should return that, so `return acc.concat(...)`

Comment: The arrow function does it because there's no parentheses (if I correctly understand what you meant)

Comment: True, I failed to notice that you didn't use parentheses, good tip to myself :D

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the properties are static, you could use following solution.

```js
var arr = [{ name: "A1", arr: [1,2] }, { name: "A2", arr: [1] }], res = [];
    arr.forEach(v => v.arr.length > 1 ? v.arr.forEach(c => res.push({name: v.name, arr: [c]})) : res.push(v));
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Reduce is cleaner imo, so you don't need to declare this separate `res` variable.

Comment: @IanSegers *"you don't need to declare this separate res variable"* - how can you be so sure that OP wants to mutate his original array?

Comment: I might have misunderstood something, if you use `reduce` you're not mutating the original array, you return a new one.

Comment: @IanSegers Exactly. But anyways you still have to declare a new, separate variable to hold the result, don't you?

Comment: That's true, my bad, I just like it to I assign a variable at the moment of declaration. But that's my personal taste, I agree, in the end, you need to declare anyway an extra variable for the result

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could map the items of the array in an object and map the outer name property to the new result set, as this answer of [ryeballar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3450034/ryeballar) of [Flatten an nested array of objects using Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357506/1447675) suggest.

```js
var data = [{ name: "A1", arr: [1, 2] }, { name: "A2", arr: [1] }],
    result = _.flatMap(data, 
        item => _.map(_.map(item.arr,
            v => ({ arr: [v] })
        ), prop => _.defaults({ name: item.name }, prop)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

ES6 with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var data = [{ name: "A1", arr: [1, 2] }, { name: "A2", arr: [1] }],
    result = data.reduce(
        (r, a) => r.concat(a.arr.map(b => Object.assign({}, a, { arr: [b] })))
    , []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Normally i would like to go with the `.reduce()` way but it is conceptually wrong. It's wrong because reduce is for reducing and if we use it for expansion then we must be using a side effect and this is not a proper functional approach. Yet... in JS there is no functional tool to handle this sort of tasks.

So just for fun lets invent one. `Array.unfold()`

`Arrays.unfold(p,f,t,v)` takes 4 arguments.

- **p** This is a function which defines where to stop. The `p` function takes 3 arguments like many array functors do. The value, the index and the currently resulting array. It shall return a Boolean value. When it returns a true the recursive iteration stops.
- **f** This is a function to return the next items functional value.
- **t** This is a function to return the next argument to feed to `f` in the next turn.
- **s** Is the seed value that will be used to calculate the comfortable seat of index 0 by `f`.

So now we can implement our unfolding Array constructor for the required case.

```js
Array.unfold = function(p,f,t,s){
  var res = [],
   runner = v =>  p(v,res.length-1,res) ? [] : (res = res.concat(f(v)), runner(t(v)), res);
  return runner(s);
};

var data   = [{ name: "A1", arr: [1,2] }, { name: "A2", arr: [1] }],
    result = Array.unfold(v => v.length === 0,
                          v => v[0].arr.map(n => Object.assign({},v[0],{arr:[n]})),
                          v => v.slice(1),
                          data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Thank you Redu for your help!