# Dynamically display table column/row with data that contains different size of nested array?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, frontend, element-ui

I'm trying to display the data that I took from firestore and want to display it on a table using Vue.js and Element UI. I've tried looking for a solution but most shows for fixed amount of data whilst for my case I have an uneven number of data.

The structure of my data are as follows:

```
suppData: [{
  comp_name: "company 1",
  country: "country 1",
  contInfo: [{
     cpName: "John Doe",
     phone: "123123",
     email: "john@doe.com
  },
  prodList: [{
     product: "eggs",
     product: "shoes"
  }
}],

comp_name: "company 2",
      country: "country 2",
      contInfo: [{
         cpName: "Jack Doe",
         phone: "1231231",
         email: "jack@doe.com
      },
      {
         cpName: "Michelle",
         phone: "12412",
         email: "mmichelle@doe.com
      },
      prodList: [{
         product: "eggs",
      }
    }]
}]
```

The code I'm using for the table right now, played around with other methods such as formatter, flattening the data, but can't get it to work so help is appreciated!

```
    <el-table-column label="Company Name" prop="company_name"></el-table-column>
    <el-table-column label="Country" prop="country"></el-table-column>
    <el-table-column label="Contacs" prop="contactName.cpName"></el-table-column>
```

Comment: You can use v-for directives to display a list or array, https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for

Answer (score 1):

For adding a `row` you just have to add an entry to your dataset. For columns you could create a seperate `array` with column data. You could manage this array yourself. This is an example how you could achieve it:

HTML:

```
<template>
  <el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column v-for="item in tableStructure" :key="item.prop" prop="item.prop" :label="item.label"></el-table-column>
  </el-table>
      
  <el-button @click="addRow">Add row</el-button>
  <el-button @click="addColumn">Add column</el-button>
</template>
```

JS:

```
data() {
        return {
          tableStructure: [
            { label: "date", prop:"date" },
            { label: "name", prop:"name" }
          ],
          tableData: [{
            date: '2016-05-03',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }, {
            date: '2016-05-02',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }, {
            date: '2016-05-04',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }, {
            date: '2016-05-01',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }]
        }
      },
      methods: {
        addRow() {
          this.tableData.push({
            date: '2021-001-01',
            name: 'New row',
            address: 'Other address'
          })
        },
        addColumn() {
          this.tableStructure.push({ label: "address", prop:"address" })
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is the example in codepen: https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/mdrOXgZ?editors=1011

Comment: Ah sorry I missworded my question, my issue is in displaying the data of an array within an array using element-ui table (though any other table is fine)

Comment: You have to flatten your data first so you have one flat array. You could use a `computed ` value for this.

Comment: Any tips on how I might be able to achieve that? (thanks for the help by the way!)

Comment: Here is an example how you could flatten your data https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357506/575468